# How to call a function in a member initialization list?

Tags: c++, constructor

I have the following simple c++ (RAII pattern) wrapper around `jpeg_decompress_struct` (ijg/libjpeg-turbo):

```
class Decompress {
  typedef jpeg_decompress_struct *ptr;
  jpeg_decompress_struct srcinfo;

 public:
  Decompress() { jpeg_create_decompress(&srcinfo); }
  ~Decompress() { jpeg_destroy_decompress(&srcinfo); }
  operator ptr() { return &srcinfo; }
  jpeg_decompress_struct *operator->() { return &srcinfo; }
};
```

I am happy with this code, and I'd like to keep `srcinfo` as it is now (on the stack, just like upstream [expect it](https://github.com/libjpeg-turbo/libjpeg-turbo/blob/2.1.1/djpeg.c#L540).)

Is there a way to rewrite the above constructor using a member initialization list ? I'd like to pass the check of gcc `-Weffc++`.

Current warning is:

```
jpeg.cxx:92:3: error: ‘acme::Decompress::srcinfo’ should be initialized in the member initialization list [-Werror=effc++]
   92 |   Decompress() { jpeg_create_decompress(&srcinfo); }
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: What error/warning are you getting right now that you are trying to avoid?

Comment: Show declaration of `jpeg_decompress_struct`. If it's POD then add `srcinfo = {0};` in constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If (which we can probably safely assume here) `jpeg_create_decompress()` can operate on a `jpeg_decompress_struct` containing undefined values, then the code you posted is fine as is . I wouldn't personally touch it.

However, the question can still be answered as aksed:

Most question formulated as "How to do __blank__ in an initialization list" have the same answer: Do it in a function.

```
jpeg_decompress_struct make_initialized_jds() {
  jpeg_decompress_struct result;
  jpeg_create_decompress(&result);
  return result;
}

class Decompress {
  typedef jpeg_decompress_struct *ptr;
  jpeg_decompress_struct srcinfo;

 public:
  Decompress() : srcinfo(make_initialized_jds()) {}
  ~Decompress() { jpeg_destroy_decompress(&srcinfo); }
  operator ptr() { return &srcinfo; }
  jpeg_decompress_struct *operator->() { return &srcinfo; }
};
```

In modern compilers making use of NRVO, this won't even result in any additional overhead.

**Edit:** From the updated question: If you just want to make the warning go away, you can explicitely zero-initialize the struct using member initialization:

```
class Decompress {
  jpeg_decompress_struct srcinfo = {0};          // <---- here
  typedef jpeg_decompress_struct *ptr = nullptr; // <---- might as well...

 public:
  Decompress() { jpeg_create_decompress(&srcinfo); }
  ~Decompress() { jpeg_destroy_decompress(&srcinfo); }
  operator ptr() { return &srcinfo; }
  jpeg_decompress_struct *operator->() { return &srcinfo; }
};
```

This will give `srcinfo` a defined value before invoking `jpeg_create_decompress()`.

Comment: No additional overhead for runtime performance, but additional thunk boilerplate.  I agree with "the code is fine as is".  (I presume the JPEG API is C based.). I like the edit to zero initialize the struct.